# make automatic move between columns and cell?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

It's possible make automatic move between columns and cell?

For Example:
I want only column A,B,C(Column A-item number Column B-LP(license plate) Column-C Location
I want scan barcode and cursor from column A2 go to right to Column B2 form column B to Column C2 but from column C2 I want back to Column A3 next Cell like automatic is possible ?
now I have like this but still I must use Ctrl+a then I back to Column A3.

Comment: Automatic move on which trigger? Something needs to trigger that move what should that be?

Comment: automatic move from D2 to A3... again from D3 to A4

Comment: for example active cell A2 I scan bar code number goes to A2 .From A2 direct to B2 then go to C2 and from C2 go to D2 and From D2 i want automatic move to A3 and scan new bar code

Comment: Sub next12()
'
' next12 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'
    
    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -4).Range("A1").Select
    
   
    ActiveCell.Select
End Sub

    
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'select a character's score



Sub SelectScore()

'given a character's score, select

'the character on their left

ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Select

End Sub

Comment: Sub next12()
'
' next12 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'
    
    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -4).Range("A1").Select
    
   
    ActiveCell.Select
End Sub

    
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'select a character's score



Sub SelectScore()

'given a character's score, select

'the character on their left

ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Select

End Sub

Comment: but this working only with Ctrl+d

Comment: Please note that code in comments is not readable at all. Instead always [edit] your original question to add code. • Please checkout the answers posted below, both should do what you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy alternative is to format the columns A to C as table (list object). And change the option [Cell Movement After Enter](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T006712_Cell_Movement_After_Enter.html) in Excel options to `right` instead of down. Entering data will then go from column C to A in the next line:

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: The values are just typed in and confirmed with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Because column C is the last one in the table now it starts over in the next line column A.</sup>*

---

The cell movement direction can also be changed by code

```
Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlToRight
```

so you can eg. change it if the workbook opens and change it back if it closes, so it doesn't affect all your workbooks.

```
Option Explicit

Dim MoveAfterReturnDirection_ORIGINAL As Long

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MoveAfterReturnDirection_ORIGINAL = Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection
    Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlToRight
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = MoveAfterReturnDirection_ORIGINAL
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If the scanner is set to press Enter, use this piece of code in `Worksheet_Change` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Cells.count = 1 Then
        If Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column = 2 Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ElseIf Target.Column = 3 Then
            Target.Offset(1, -2).Select
        End If
   End If
End Sub
```

It will not move the selection if you modify something outside the A:C columns.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But I observed that such a condition is not necessary, in fact...

Comment: But I recommend to check if `Target` is only a single cell or a range of multiple cells. Because this code breaks the ability of copying entire rows. Allow this code only to run if `Target` is a single cell.

Comment: Correct, again. I will update it... Even if it is almost impossible that such a situation occurs in case of scanning followed by Enter.

Comment: Not in case of scanning but if you need to work with that data later the event is still active and will annoy you a lot.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: Agreed, also! Now I am thinking that maybe some bar codes are not well printed and he must manually introduce the values. Even in such a situation is difficult to input data in a multiple selection, even if you wish to do it... Anyhow, nothing wrong will happen conditioning in the suggested way! :-)

Comment: Easiest example I can imagine is you need to delete a row (eg, scanner scanned it wrongly). Without the check for mutliple cells it will throw an error if you delete a row. Now as it is it should work properly. Of course moving the cell cursor manually by code always confuses and can result in unwanted behaviour.

Comment: For a solution without code and without odd side effects resulting out of the code see my answer :)